# How can I achieve remote ZFS snapshot and restoration with logical domains?

Tags: solaris, snapshot, high-availability, sparc, zfs

Hardware: Solaris SPARC with ZFS filesystems

I have setup the primary domain(dom0) on machine 1 with a logical domain called test.
Additionally I also have machine 2 where the test-backup is supposed to reside and act as a failover. test-backup is a logical domain that is supposed to replicate the original and is inactive but will be brought up when machine 1 fails.

May I know how to achieve the above?

I have already tested the following from dom0:

```
zfs snapshot rpool/logicaldomain/test/datadisk@sync0
zfs send rpool/logicaldomain/test/datadisk@sync0 | zfs recv rpool/logicaldomain/test-backup/datadisk
```

but whenever I bring up the machine and run zpool status, the disk's state is faulted and the cksum is corrupted.

Comment: What's the output from `zfs send` and `zfs recv`?